# Martian tries to understand High heels

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember excellent story where alien (might not have been Martian) reports back on viewing earthlings and the description of half of them shackled in torturous footwear. And brilliant descriptions of pushchair pushing too. But I cannot find it. Anyone any clues? I think it was circa '79? Because I was at uni and link it with 'a Martian sends a postcard home' poem by Craig raine but it's not that. Want to publish an excerpt of it as postcard for Leeds Postcards. Hope someone might guide me in right direction. Thanks for reading

Comment: I read a story that sounds a bit like this. Was the Martian found in a garden shed, and a young boy and his grandmother looked after him for a while, including taking him out in a pushchair disguised as a human child?